# Missing root tag in xml

Tags: xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Template/>
<tmp_name>hello</tmp_name>
<tmp_subject>Launch Business</tmp_subject>
<EContent><![CDATA[<p>xdfgdfgdfgdf</p>]]></EContent>
<PDFContent><![CDATA[<p>gdfgdfgdfgdfg</p>`enter code here`]]></PDFContent>
```

Why am I missing close root tag? everything should be fine only close root tag i missed... here is my code

```
        $name=$_POST['tmp_name'];           
        $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
        $xml->formatOutput = true;
        $root = $xml->createElement('Template');
        $root = $xml->appendChild($root);

        $title = $xml->createElement('tmp_name');
        $title = $xml->appendChild($title);

        $text = $xml->createTextNode($name);
        $text = $title->appendChild($text);

        $title1 = $xml->createElement('tmp_subject');
        $title1 = $xml->appendChild($title1);

        $text1 = $xml->createTextNode($_POST['tmp_subject']);
        $text1 = $title1->appendChild($text1);

        $title2 = $xml->createElement('EContent');
        $title2 = $xml->appendChild($title2);

        $text2 = $xml->createCDATASection($_POST['EContent']);
        $text2 = $title2->appendChild($text2);

        $title3 = $xml->createElement('PDFContent');
        $title3 = $xml->appendChild($title3);

        $text3 = $xml->createCDATASection($_POST['PDFContent']);
        $text3 = $title3->appendChild($text3);




        $xml->save($curr_path.'../../../templates/'.$_POST['tmp_name'].'.xml');
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are appending the title etc tags to the document. You should append them to the `$root` node. So, instead of;

```
$title = $xml->appendChild($title);
```

your code should be;

```
$title = $root->appendChild($title);
```

Comment: can you explain in detail i did'nt get you?